# Is it possible to remove Weston toolbar?

Tags: qt, qt5, wayland, qtwayland

[image: Weston desktop with toolbar]

Is it possible to have weston run without the toolbar at the top and change the background to black. So that when i have a script in init.d it calls weston first than my qt5 app? such as:

```
weston &
/home/root/app -platform wayland
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change the background settings in weston.ini. For the toolbar you just have to return 0 in want_panel function in clients/desktop_shell.c

Comment: Thank you. i created a git patch yocto and it built without the toolbar.

Answer (score 5):

You can also just add panel-location string weston.ini [shell] section like this :

[shell]
panel-location=""

Answer (score 1):

It is seemed it is determined by the `shell/modules` loaded when launching `weston`, by default `desktop-shell.so` is loaded. You can reference to the [man page](https://www.mankier.com/5/weston.ini) of *weston.ini* to try to change it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. This is solution:

open: /etc/xdg/weston/weston.ini

add:

```
panel-position=none
```

to this file

open terminal or debug, type:

```
systemctl restart weston
```

reboot

Answer (score 1):

To combine the possible solutions, just by adding the settings as below to your weston.ini helped me.

```
**[shell]
panel-location=""
panel-position=none**
```

Also, Weston.ini is picked up based on this precedence order:-

```
$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/weston.ini   (if $XDG_CONFIG_HOME is set)
$HOME/.config/weston.ini      (if $HOME is set)
weston/weston.ini in each
           $XDG_CONFIG_DIR           (if $XDG_CONFIG_DIRS is set)
       /etc/xdg/weston/weston.ini    (if $XDG_CONFIG_DIRS is not set)
       <current dir>/weston.ini      (if no variables were set)
```

where environment variable $HOME is the user's home directory, and $XDG_CONFIG_HOME is the user  specific  configuration  directory,  and  $XDG_CONFIG_DIRS  is a colon ':' delimited listed of configuration base directories, such as /etc/xdg-foo:/etc/xdg.

Answer (score 1):

Run as `weston --shell="kiosk-shell.so"`

Weston’s kiosk-shell is a simple shell targeted at single-app/kiosk use cases. It makes all top-level application windows fullscreen, and supports defining which applications to place on particular outputs.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed same issue on weston version 9 by modifying /etc/xdg/weston/weston.ini

panel-position=none

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33499876)