# startup qt app in wayland weston

Tags: qt, embedded-linux, wayland, qtwayland

I use wayland weston and qt 5.6.2 in my arm board and start my app with bellow commands

```
openvt -s -- weston --backend=fbdev-backend.so --idle-time=0
/root/myapp -platform wayland-egl
```

but before my app starts, it shown weston shell.I need to start my qt app at startup without showing weston shell, is it possible?

Comment: Try eiditing options available for [shell] in ~/.config/weston.ini

Comment: There is no option for that! Do you know specific options?

Comment: Can you share your weston.ini and how you are starting `"openvt -s -- weston --backend..."`? in init.*?

Comment: It's normal weston.ini I don't have any special configuration in it

Answer (score 2):

You can try the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30605949/is-it-possible-to-remove-weston-toolbar) and also change the background to black.

However, if you're just going to run one application fullscreen, you could skip Weston altogether and just run the client with the `eglfs` backend. I.e:

```
/root/myapp -platform eglfs
```

or perhaps `linuxfb` if `eglfs` is not supported on your system.

```
/root/myapp -platform linuxfb
```

If you for some reason need to use Wayland, another thing you could do is use one of the example Qt Wayland compositors. I.e: [minimal-qml](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtwaylandcompositor-minimal-qml-example.html). And then just change the background color to black or whatever you want.

Comment: I need this because my app is multi window

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: @bobbaluba Second url is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can add following settings to config file from path `/etc/xdg/weston/weston.ini`

```
[shell]
background-image=""
background-color=0xFF000000
panel-color=0xFF000000
panel-position=none
```

the above settings will set background color to black and will remove upper panel of weston